# Is there any optimise way to create a page object?

Tags: java, selenium

I m using a Page Object Model for my automation and I am creating a page object in Test class like below.(Just a sample code)

```
public class Test1 extends TestBase {
Page1 page1;
Page2 page2;
Page3 page3;
// and continues as number of pages increases

@BeforeTest
public void initialise() {
    this.page1 = new Page1(this);
    this.page2 = new Page2(this);
    this.page3 = new Page3(this);
    // and continues as number of pages increases
}

@Test
public void firstTest() {
    // my test script starts here
}
}
```

But as my number of pages increases, number of page object creation in test class increases. I want to know if there is any other optimize way to create page object or whatever I am doing is good ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

Create a `Page class` that will extends from `TestBase`, and create specific `Pages()` class that will be child class of `Page class`.

I have created a basic project for Page object model. See the eclipse project structure below :

[image]

`TestBase` class :

```
public class TestBase {
    
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    
    public TestBase() {
        System.out.println("Test Base Bot has been activated.");
    }
    
    public Page getPageObj() {
       return new Page();
    }
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUpSuite() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Before suite executed successfully");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpTest() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        driver.get("https://fuelinsights.gasbuddy.com/Charts");
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDownClass() {
        //driver.close();
    }
}
```

TestClass `StackOverflowProblems.Java`

```
public class StackOverflowProblems extends TestBase {
    
    @Test
    public void testSO() throws InterruptedException {
        getPageObj().loginPage().loginWithUser();
    }
}
```

`Page` class

```
public class Page extends TestBase {
    
    public Page(){
        System.out.println("Page bots are now in action");
    }
    
    public LoginPage loginPage() {
        return new LoginPage();
    }
    
    public HomePage homePage() {
        return new HomePage();
    }
    
    public DashBoard dashBoardPage() {
        return new DashBoard();
    }
    
}
```

**LoginPage.Java** :

```
public class LoginPage extends Page {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='xxkkk20']")
    WebElement ele;
    
    public void loginWithUser() {
        System.out.println("Finally Bot has called this method.");
        driver.get("Your url here"); 
        System.out.println("Web drivers operations can be performed here");
        String html = ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `NullPointerException` in LoginPage class. As you suggested, I created a page class and configured PageFactory like `public PageObject() { PageFactory.initElements(TestBase.getDriver(), this); }`  and followed other steps as well. In my test class, when I call my `pageObject().getLoginPage().loginWithUser()` , I am getting `NullPointerException` while entering userName. Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `NullPointerException` basically it means object has not been initialize properly. have you created pages() method in `TestBase` class ? in your test class you should call that method like this `pages().getLoginPage().somethingelse()....`

Comment: Yes, I have created pages() method in TestBase as you suggested and the method calling is also exactly same as you have mentioned above.

Comment: in which class you have written `loginWithUser()` method ? and how are you passing driver reference ? basically where are you creating object of webdriver ?

Comment: `loginWithUser()` is written in `LoginPage()` class and I am create a webdriver object in TestBase class like `@BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        webUtility = new WebUtility(driver);
    }`

Comment: I have updated the `@BeforeClass` to have `pageFactory` and `@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='xxkkk20']")
 WebElement ele;` is written in login class for demo purpose